# IndexOutOfBoundsException Error Vector In Scala

Tags: scala, vector

I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.checkRangeConvert(Vector.scala:132)
at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.apply(Vector.scala:122)
```

This means that I am out of memory?
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4):

you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, when you try to access an index greater than number of elements in a collection or less than 0 as the vector starts from index 0.

example below,

```
scala> val vector = Vector("washington", "iowa", "california")
vector: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(washington, iowa, california)

scala> vector(0)
res4: String = washington

scala> vector(1)
res5: String = iowa

scala> vector(2)
res6: String = california
```

you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to access `index < 0` or `index >=3`,

```
scala> vector(3)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
  at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.checkRangeConvert(Vector.scala:132)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.apply(Vector.scala:122)
  ... 33 elided
```

> how can i fix it?

check if the index you are accessing is `lesser than 0` or `greater than number of elements` in a vector or use `.lift` on collection.

```
scala> vector.lift(0)
res14: Option[String] = Some(washington)

scala> vector.lift(3)
res15: Option[String] = None
```

releated question - [How to get an Option from index in Collection in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231337/432903)

Comment: But in this case you are receiving a code 3, not a code -1

Comment: @Vlad because in your case you might be trying to access index `-1` as `vector(-1)` while your vector indices start from `[0 to n]`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the `-1`th element of your vector.  In Scala there are not circular indexes like in some other languages, so you are only allowed to specify positive indexes (and zero).  Here is an example:

```
val v = Vector("a", "b", "c")
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(a, b, c)

scala> v(0)
res1: String = a

scala> v(1)
res2: String = b

scala> v(-1)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
  at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.checkRangeConvert(Vector.scala:123)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.apply(Vector.scala:114)
```

As you can see, when I specify the indexes `0` or `1` everything is fine, but when I try `-1` I get the same error you are seeing.  The error not in how you are accessing the vector, but the part of the vector you are trying to access.